# How to get response data from servlet inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I have this simple html piece of code, whenever I click on any of the buttons the server will send back some string, I want it to be displayed in `#response` div.

```
<form target="_self" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="35"><input type="button" id="btncreate" value="create" onclick="getData();"></td>
            <td width="35"><input type="button" id="btnupdate" value="update"></td>
            <td width="30"><input type="button" id="btndelete" value="delete"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name : </td>                    
            <td><input type="text" id="name" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>File : </td>
            <td><input type="file" id="filname" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

In JS i am using `XMLHttpRequest` or `ActiveXObject` based on browser to send request to servlet, and i can get the response in `client.responseText()` so how can i direct this output to my `#response` div?

Here is my JS

```
function getData()
{
var client;
var data;
var url_action="/temp/getData";
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    client=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    client=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
client.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (client.readyState==4 && client.status==200)
    {
         document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=client.responseText; 
    }
};
data="name="+document.getElementById("name").value+"&file="+document.getElementById("filname").value;
client.open("POST",url_action,true);
client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.send(data);
}
```

Servlet post method

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    log.info("Good");
    out.println("Good to go");
}
```

But using js script not jquery, i am not able to get the output from servlet

Thanks all for a jQuery code, any alternative in Javascript?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply do

```
success: function(data) { 
var res = client.responseText();
$('#response').html(res);
// or $('#response').append(res); 
});
```

in simple **java script**: `document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=res;`

Comment: @diEcho: Thanks, i'll try and get back, also what is the alternative in JS, just for curiosity

Comment: update my answer , reference : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: @diEcho: Thanks a lot, i got othere answers too, but you were the first, so i'll give it to you :)

Comment: @diEcho: Don't worry, I tried accepting, and it says I cannot accept any answer till 5 mins, so just wait for 5 mins :) thanks

Comment: @diEcho: One more small request, can you look into my edited code, its passing the data to servlet but I am not getting the data displayed in the div, can you point out where is the mistake here? Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery in your project:

`$('#response').load("http://url...")`

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: using jquery it works, but by using JS i tried and it is not giving any output, I have edited the question to show my js, can you help finding what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery (assumtion based on the question tags), you can use the [`.load()`-method](http://api.jquery.com/load):

```
$('#some-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#response').load('url/to/entry/point');
});
```

This has the benefit of jQuery doing all of the ajax work for you (creating and handling XMLHttpRequest and ActiveX stuff).